# How to keep the innerHTML fully occupied inside a div

Tags: html, css

The code as follows :

I have a `p` element inside a `div` tag. I am not getting the `innerHTML` of the `div` fully occupied inside. When I increase the font size, the whole size of the `div` increases. I want the `div` to be as it is, with the `innerHTML` covering it:

```css
.hit-the-floor {
  color: #AA5522;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

```html
<td style='width:10%;text-align:center;'>
  <div  id='div1'>
    <p class='hit-the-floor'>SAMPLE</p>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: missing javascript code...?

Comment: give your div width and height

Comment: thats  css question. not javascript

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a `height` for `div1` so it doesn't collapse. Then add `margin: 0;` to `.hit-the-floor`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zxLqmbht/

I added a border to `div1` so you can see the div and used `height: 175px` as an example. With `margin: 0;` set, you can now modify the font-size without affecting the div size (until it exceeds the div's height, of course).

Was this what you were looking for?